# Mysql_fetch_assoc() does not display anything

Tags: php, mysql, rows

This time i have an issues with mysql_fetch_assoc(), after used it i can't see anything on the screen. It's supposed to print on screen a bunch of records, instead, i have only a withe screen.

So, here my code:

```
$selected="SELECT name,namep,price,time
         FROM img
         INNER JOIN products on img.id_img=products.id_img
         WHERE img.id_img='$rand_n'";
  $selected = mysql_query($selected)
        or die ("Impossible execute the query SEL"). mysql_error();
  //____________________________________________________________________
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($selected))
        {
            if(isset($row) && !empty($row))
                {
                    printf("Product name: &nbsp %s", $row['namep']);
                echo '<br />';
                echo "Price: &nbsp"; echo $row['price'];
                echo '<br />';
                echo "Data: &nbsp"; echo $row['time'];
                echo '<br />';
                echo "Immage: <img src='".$row['name']."' alt='Image'>";
                echo '<hr> <br />';

                $value--;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Yep, qualcosa decisamente non va!";
            }
        }
```

Someone could be so kind to explain me why it doesn't work? Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Enable error reporting](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/)

Comment: What is the value of `$rand_n`?

Comment: turn on error reporting at the beginning of the file `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: i think this statement is not correct: `die ("Impossible execute the query SEL"). mysql_error()` it should be like this: `die ("Impossible execute the query SEL ". mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$selected="SELECT ........";
$selected2 = mysql_query($selected)
    or die ("Impossible execute the query SEL"). mysql_error();
if(mysql_num_rows($selected2) > 0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($selected2))
     {

       printf("Product name: &nbsp %s", $row['namep']);
            echo '<br />';
            echo "Price: &nbsp"; echo $row['price'];
            echo '<br />';
            echo "Data: &nbsp"; echo $row['time'];
            echo '<br />';
            echo "Immage: <img src='".$row['name']."' alt='Image'>";
            echo '<hr> <br />';
        }
}
else
        {
            echo "Yep, qualcosa decisamente non va!";
        }
```